# How to plot graph using float values with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I prepared following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([100, 400, 1600, 6400,25600, 102400])
y4 = np.array([868, 3179, 3418, 4195, 4941, 5000])
#y4 = np.array([-38.,28.,273.,1256., 5164.,20830.])
print(y4.dtype)  #int32
plt.figure(0)
plt.plot(y4,x1,label='label1')
plt.ylabel('y-label')
plt.legend(['label1'])
plt.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

It outputs following graph:

[image]

If I use commented `y4`:

```
#y4 = np.array([868, 3179, 3418, 4195, 4941, 5000])
y4 = np.array([-38.,28.,273.,1256., 5164.,20830.])
print(y4.dtype)  #float64
```

It plots straight line:

[image]

Why float64 y-axis values does not work and plot all six points?

PS: I am on python 3.8.3

Comment: it is plotting all of your data. The range of the data is just so large that can't see the comparatively minuscule changes in slope. Here's a good exercise: draw that figure by hand on graph paper.

Comment: also, you're plotting `y4` on the x-axis. Is that what you want?

Comment: as an aside, if you compute the slopes between each coordinate pair, it is a pretty straight line: `array([4.55, 4.9 , 4.88, 4.91, 4.9 ])`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you believe that line is not plotted with all the 6 points. It is actually ploting all the 6 points. They just happen to lie on a straight line. You can enable `marker='o'` within `plt.plot` to see that.